# SQL query to automatically select and sum 'grade columns' based on student performance

Tags: java, sql

Please I need real help….

I have a table with student grades and their related positions for that grade - like this:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|  Name   | Grade1 | G1_Pos | Grade2 | G2_Pos | Grade3 | G3_Pos | Grade4 | Grade5 | Agregate |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|  james  |    4   | 3rd    |     6  | 4th    |    1   | 1st    |     3  |      2 |          |
|  Mavis  |    1   | 1st    |     1  | 1st    |    3   | 3rd    |     2  |      3 |          |
|  john   |    5   | 4th    |     3  | 2nd    |    4   | 4th    |     4  |      4 |          |
|  bendo  |    2   | 2nd    |     5  | 3rd    |    2   | 2nd    |     1  |      2 |          |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

NB: Pos meaning Position..

I want to sum up the Grade Columns for each student and store their result in the aggregate column. But instead of summing all grade columns, I want to sum up only four grade columns out of the five grade columns. Grade4 and Grade5 Columns must be part of the four columns to be added.

And for that I only have this code

```
String sql = "update jhs1 set Agregate=(SELECT SUM(Grade4+Grade5) AS ST) WHERE ID = jhs1.ID";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.execute();
```

and for the  remaining three Grade columns, I want a code that will check and pick out the best two Grade Columns of the three Grade Columns the student performed well in. Eg. If james's result is  Grade1=4 ,Grade2= 6,Grade3=1..the code must select only the best two Grades of the three grades which in this 
example its Grade1 = 4 and Grade3 = 1 and add the result to Grade4 and Grade5.

So in james case it will be 4+1+3+2 = 10.

Please how do I write such a SQL query and get a result like the table below:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|  Name   | Grade1 | G1_Pos | Grade2 | G2_Pos | Grade3 | G3_Pos | Grade4 | Grade5 | Agregate |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|  james  |    4   | 3rd    |     6  | 4th    |    1   | 1st    |     3  |      2 |      10  |
|  Mavis  |    1   | 1st    |     1  | 1st    |    3   | 3rd    |     2  |      3 |       7  |
|  john   |    5   | 4th    |     3  | 2nd    |    4   | 4th    |     4  |      4 |      15  |
|  bendo  |    2   | 2nd    |     5  | 3rd    |    2   | 2nd    |     1  |      2 |       7  |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Please I will appreciate all help and suggestions.. thank you very much

Comment: I have an issue with your table design.  Rather than storing separate grades in separate columns, I think you should be storing those grades in separate records.  If you do this, aggregating and just about anything else you have in mind would be relatively easy.

Comment: the grades are seperate because they represent different subject scores. example maths has its grade column, english has its grade column etc. if i was dealing with just one subject it will be much easier since i will have just one grade column. but please if you have another way of calculating aggregates please kindly share with me.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Eg. If james's result is Grade1=4 ,Grade2= 6,Grade3=1..the code must
>   select only the best two Grades of the three grades which in this
>   example its Grade1 = 4 and Grade3 = 1 and add the result to Grade4 and
>   Grade5.

Instead of focusing your efforts on finding a way to pick the two best grades and then sum them, it is easier to find the worst grade and subtract it from the sum of all 3.

Something like:

```
SELECT grade1+grade2+grade3 - least( grade1, grade2, grade3 )
FROM .....
```

Note: [LEAST( x,y,z,....)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions075.htm) function pick the least of the list of expressions.

---

If "the least value" is determined by `G2_Pos` column (the greatest `Gx_Pos` determines the least `Grade`), it could be something like this:

```
SELECT grade1+grade2+grade3 -
       CASE greatest( G1_Pos , G2_Pos , G3_Pos )
          WHEN G1_Pos THEN Grade1
          WHEN G2_Pos THEN grade2
          WHEN G3_Pos THEN grade3
       END
FROM .....
```

The problem might be with the same grades, for example when there will be:

```
+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| G1_Pos |  grade1 | G2_Pos | grade2 | G2_Pos | grade3 |
+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 3rd    |      10 | 3rd    |      5 | 3rd    |     2  |
+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

then this expression will always pick `grade1`, that is 10 in this example.

Comment: please so someting like this @ krokodilko.....String sql = "update jhs1 set Agregate=(SELECT SUM((grade4+grade5)+(grade1+grade2+grade3 - least( grade1, grade2, grade3)))AS ST) WHERE ID = jhs1.ID";

Comment: thanks @Krokodilko...this looks tougher than i imagined...in reality lets say a student does 4 core subjects and 5 elective subjects..and his best results in 2 elective subjects must be added to the 4 core subjects to make his aggregate mark... please how will you prefer i go about that. am using sqlite3 dbms please

Comment: `4 core subjects and 5 elective subjects` - that is in total 9 subjects/grades. How is it related to the sample table from the question ? There are only 5 grades grade1..5 there.

Comment: yes boss.. the table was a sample since i didnt want the question to be too long..in the nut shell best two grades of the five subjects must be added to the 4 core. so the total number of columns to be added together will be six. my problem is just how to get the best two from the five grades thats why i used the table sample @krokodilko